# Lucene: How to use StandardTokenizer in conjunction with my own Tokenizer

Tags: lucene, tokenize

I'm building a Tokenizer that will take text and split at white spaces and add in sentence and paragraph tokens ([here's a question related to that if you're interested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10593715/348056)) but in addition to running this, I would like to also be able to run the StandardTokenizer (and StandardFilter) as well so that I get smarter tokenization of words. Here I have sort of a catch22.

- If I run the StandardTokenizer (and possibly StandardFilter) first, then I get smarter tokenization, but I don't have any punctuations/whitespace/capital letters upon which to base my sentence/paragraph detection.
- If I use my Tokenizer first, then I am able to include the requisite tokens for sentences and paragraphs, but I'm unable benefit from the smart tokenization of the StandardTokenizer and certainly unable to benefit from the StandardFilter which requires the StandardTokenizer to already be run.

**What pattern should I use to get around this?** Most practically, I probably just want to augment the TokenStream of the StandardTokenizer with sentence and paragraph markers. Though more generally I might want to use the sentence/paragraph tokenizer with any other tokenizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually change the grammar of StandardTokenizer, and generate Tokenizer for your custom requirements. This is what I did at [Generating a custom Tokenizer for new TokenStream API using JFlex/ Java CC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846305/generating-a-custom-tokenizer-for-new-tokenstream-api-using-jflex-java-cc)